# Add an AND condition only IF a certain expression is true

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add an AND condition only if an expression is true, otherwise the AND condition should be ignored.

I'm supposed to group concat the phone numbers if they have IsConcat set to true, otherwise I need to select the first one which doesn't have IsConcat set to true.

What I've tried so far:

```sql
SELECT IF(p.IsConcat = 1, GROUP_CONCAT(p.PhoneNumber), p.PhoneNumber) AS 'PhoneNumber'
FROM phones p 
WHERE p.IdStudent = _idStudent
AND IF(p.IsConcat = 1, TRUE, '') -- only check if IsConcat = 1 otherwise i don't need the AND statement
LIMIT 1
```

I saw somewhere online that TRUE is being used in if statements, thought it would work but it didn't.

I have some mock data: Two students, the student with Id = 1 has 5 phones and only 3 of them have IsConcat = 1 -> the output works good since it does a group concat and shows only those 3 numbers.

The student with Id = 2 has two phone numbers and both have IsConcat = 0, which means I need to select the first one, without checking if IsConcat = 1, that's why I added LIMIT 1. In that case it outputs NULL.

The expected output if the phones table has any numbers for the appropriate student with IsConcat = 1 should group_concat only them.
If the phones table has no phone numbers with IsConcat = 1 for the appropriate student, it should output the first phone number.

Comment: can you show what output is getting ?

Comment: Sure.
I have some mock data: Two students, the student with Id = 1 has 5 phones and only 3 of them have IsConcat = 1 -> the output works good since it does a group concat and shows only those 3 numbers.
The student with Id = 2 has two phone nunmbers and both have IsConcat = 0, which means I need to select the first one, without checking if IsConcat = 1, that's why I added LIMIT 1. In that case it outputs NULL.

Comment: It's my first time posting here i'm not sure how to attach a screenshot in the comments, should I edit the post?

Comment: yeah you can edit and some more information. it is difficult to understand right now

Comment: Use `SELECT ... , CASE WHEN SUM(p.IsConcat = 1) THEN GROUP_CONCAT(phone) ELSE ANY_VALUE(phone) END AS phone, ...`.

Comment: Edit the post to clarify the question, or answer other people's questions. What does the GROUP_CONCAT do without a GROUP BY clause? You should include sample data and expected output; I don't understand how IsConcat appears: when it appears on multiple rows of the same IdStudent can it be different, some 0 some 1?

Comment: *IF(p.IsConcat = 1, GROUP_CONCAT(p.PhoneNumber), p.PhoneNumber)* You cannot combine aggregated and non-aggregated versions of the column in the expression.

Comment: @tinazmu yes the IsConcat is a boolean, there can be many phone numbers attached to a specific IdStudent and they can have IsConcat either 0 or 1, can be mixed

Comment: So, If you have a mixture of 0s and 1s for the same idstudent, what is the expected output? And what is your GROUP BY

Comment: @tinazmu in that case only the rows with 1s should be group concat-ed. I don't have a group by, is it needed?

Comment: I don't really know MySQL, but group_concat (mysql specific) appears to be an aggregation/grouping function. Yes, you need one: GROUP BY İdstudent
I would say.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, thank you @Akina for giving me the idea to use SUM().
If SUM(p.IsConcat) > 1, it goes to a subquery and does group_concat to ones that have IsConcat = 1.
This is the final solution

```
SELECT IF(SUM(p.IsConcat) > 0, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pp.PhoneNumber)
                                        FROM phones pp 
                                        WHERE pp.IdStudent = _idStudent
                                        AND pp.IsConcat = 1
                                        LIMIT 1
                               ), p.PhoneNumber)
FROM phones p 
WHERE p.IdStudent = _idStudent
LIMIT 1
```